# Change detection not triggered on some event

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a component that `subscribes` to an `Observable` from a `service`. When the `observable` emits its `next` value some change happen in my component. The strange thing is that the component will or will not update the view depending on how the `next` value has been generated. If I understand this correctly some events have been monkey patched by angular 2 as to trigger change detection and some haven't been. MIDI event are one of those that haven't (which makes kinda sens).

If the service looks for click events in order to trigger the next value, the change is reflected in the view. Therefor the change detection happens.

If the service looks for keyboard events same thing, the change detection happens.

However, when the service use a MIDI event, no change detection happens.

Here some code :

```
export class App {

  arr = [
      {id: 1, status: false},
      {id: 2, status: false},
      {id: 3, status: false}
    ];

  thing = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer,
              private ser:Ser,
              private midi: MidiService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    // listening to click events, will trigger change detection
    this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
      console.log("Left click", event);
      this.thing.next(1);
    });
    this.thing.subscribe( v => this.toggle(v));
    // my midi service events will call the toggle method however the 
    // changes won't be displayed in the view
    this.midi.notesPayed$.subscribe(v => this.toggle(v));
  }
```

And here is a plnkr :

https://plnkr.co/edit/SS6jwgQg4TVdOCC05cNV?p=preview

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature from the underlying workings of angular 2. In any case I would like to know **why** this happens. The concrete issue is easily resolvable by calling the change detection myself, so I don't need a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's known behavior. The MIDI API is not covered by zone.js and therefore Angulare doesn't get notified to run change detection.

Either inject `zone:NgZone` and wrap the code that changes the model with `this.zone.run(() => {...})`

or inject `cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` and invoke change detection after the change by calling `this.cdRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: The `cdRef.detectChanges()` approach seems to not work anymore in angular 14. Any ideas why ?
The zone.run() approach works.

Comment: @Dacian I don't know. I'm not following Angular changes that closely anymore.